# Bootstrap design container-fluid with differens color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to achieve the following:

Have a fluid container with one background color on each side - but the separator should be two cols in the inside container.

I tried to describe it in this picture. Is this even possible? 
[image]

Comment: Please provide some plunker/jsfiddle/codepen.

Comment: you can use background: gradient() property for this on both side with different color

Comment: Link to the codepen is: http://codepen.io/bootmartin/pen/rxeVOj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using psuedo element before and after on .container-fluid class or give any other class name.
Here is a code pen demo:

```
`http://codepen.io/duptitung/pen/adNOpV`
```

Answer (score 2):

use css positions and after/before see the link below:
[Codepen](http://codepen.io/re5ive/pen/XXdJwN)

```css
.container {
  background: #ddd;
  height: 250px;
}
.extra1 {
  height: 250px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}
.extra2 {
  height: 250px;
  background: #000;
}
.extra1:before {
  content: '';
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300%;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  left: -200%;
}
.extra2:before {
  content: '';
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300%;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  right: -200%;
}
.your-things {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 extra1">
      <div class="your-things">
        <p>.col-md-4</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 extra2">
      <div class="your-things">
        <p>.col-md-8</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting! Will try this one. Any negative effects?

Answer (score 0):

ya, you can give background image of the specific color and place it on that specific region

css

```
.container-fluid{
   background:url( //image link// );
   background-position: // arrange image   //  ;
   background-size: auto 100%;
}
```